# Runtime DatePicker in Non Activity class

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

can we create a runtime Date Picker Dialog from a non activity class in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create any `dialog` you need to pass the `context` (you can pass through constructor or through any function arguments )

Then to create a Date Picker Dialog

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();//To initialize with the current date 
            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dialog= new DatePickerDialog(context, mDateSetListener,
                       mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

yes u can.. create a class which has constructor that takes context/activity as arguement.. and create its object in an Activity by passing Activity instance.. now in that class create DatePicker by using this object.... i mean like `context./*what ever it takes to create a date picker`

Comment: but onCreateDialog() overriden method can only be in an activity class.......then how can we use that method?????

Comment: U can manually create a dialog using the same context.. no need to override that method..

Comment: but in showDialog(int id) inbuilt method call itself onCreateDialog()